# How to access id of onSelectRow in delOptions action method in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

//Hidden Input element

//my grid details: 
 $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditedEventData", "Calendar" ,new{ })' + '?CountryId=' + @countryid + '&CityId=' + @cityid ,
            async: true,
            datatype: "json",
            colModel: [

```
            //label: "Edit Actions",
            name: "",
            width: 100,
            formatter: "actions",
            formatoptions: {
                keys: true,
                edit: true,
                add: true,
                del: true,
                editOptions: {},
                addOptions: {},
                delOptions: {    

                    url:'@Url.Action("RemoveEvent", "Calendar")'+ '?HolidayId='+document.getElementById('hdnEventId').value ,
                    //mtype: 'POST',
                }// **here it is showing hdnEventId value empty**
            }
        }
        ],
        onSelectRow : function(id){ 
            console.log('inside onSelectRow');
            alert(id);                
            document.getElementById('hdnEventId').value=id;
            alert(document.getElementById('hdnEventId').value);
        },
        sortname: 'EventDate',
        loadonce: true,
        width: 750,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 150,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"

    });
```

I am unable to access id of onSelectRow in delOptions action method.
So thought of taking a hidden html element and store the value but it is showing empty.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? jqGrid sent by default the rowid (the same as you see in `onSelectRow`) during deleting, but it's the part of HTTP body in case of usage POST request and not the part of URL. You can use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE/Firefox to see HTTP Network traffic.

Comment: I have used  Guriddo jqGrid JS bt the problem is to access the id which is my eventId in order to pass to my controller method

Comment: can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a delete is performed the id is automatically send to the server. The parameter which is obtained via post is named **id**.

If you additionally want to fill a id on deleting a rows you can use some events to fill the field you want. These are [described here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#del-grid-row). In the same documentation see the chapter *What is posted to the server* .

To fill the id in another field when a row is deleted I think the good choice is to use either serializeDelData or afterSubmit events - see the events on the same link.

When use these events the parameter **postdata**  contain the id. By example in serializeDelData (set this in delOptions) this can look like

```
serializeDelData : function( postdata ) {
    var id = postdata.id;
    document.getElementById('hdnEventId').value=id;
    return postdata;
}
```

Remember both events should return some params

Comment: thank you Oleg and Tony for helping me out now i got an idea about this:)

Comment: how do i get my selRowId accessible in @Url.Action to pass it as parameter to controller method.where selRowId is selected row id

Comment: If I understand correct the question - you do not need to add it - it is added automatically to the url you point. In the server you can get it with name **id**

Comment: yeah observed it after adding mtype:'GET' thank you @Tony:)